# Optimize query with functions in `group by` key?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I am using MySQL 8.0 and there is a slow query on a large table to be optimized.

The table contains **11 million** rows of data and it's structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `ccu` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `app_id` int NOT NULL,
  `ccu` int NOT NULL,
  `audit_create` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
  UNIQUE KEY `ccu_game_create_time_2a10bc69_idx` (`app_id`,`audit_create`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `ccu_audit_create_idx` (`audit_create`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci
```

My query is:

```
SELECT app_id, DATE(audit_create) cal_day, MAX(ccu) pcu, ROUND(AVG(ccu)) id_acu 
FROM ccu
WHERE audit_create BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 29 DAY) AND DATE(NOW())
GROUP BY app_id, DATE(audit_create)
```

The query runs over 2 seconds. I add the condition by `between ... and ...` to filter useful data.
However, the data stored in `audit_create` is in format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`, I have to use the `date` function but according to the execution plan only the `where` condition uses index(still has temporary table), the `group by` clause does not use any index at all.
[image]

I have no right to alter the table structre to add a date column. Is it possible to optimize the query to lower the query time?

Comment: Thank you for providing the `SHOW CREATE TABLE`. Most people asking for help with a query optimization don't do that even after being asked for it.

Comment: You have an index on app_id, audit_create and an index on audit_create alone. Your query wants an index that starts with audit_create (for the where clause) and continues with the app_id (for the group by). `create unique index idx on (audit_create, app_id)`;

Comment: Your query includes today midnight, but excludes all the rest of today by the way. It is more typical to use >= and < in combination: `WHERE audit_create >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 29 DAY AND audit_create < CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 DAY`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to eliminate the `Using temporary` by adding an expression index:

```
mysql> alter table ccu add key bk1 (app_id, (cast(audit_create as date)));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> explain SELECT app_id, DATE(audit_create) cal_day, 
   MAX(ccu) pcu, ROUND(AVG(ccu)) id_acu  
 FROM ccu 
 WHERE date(audit_create) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 29 DAY) AND DATE(NOW()) 
 GROUP BY app_id, cast(audit_create as date)\G 
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: ccu
   partitions: NULL
         type: index
possible_keys: bk1
          key: bk1
      key_len: 8
          ref: NULL
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where
```

Unfortunately, that EXPLAIN report shows it will use **type: index** which is an index-scan, in other words it will examine every one of the 11 million index entries. It could make it *worse* than it was in your query.

The only other suggestion I have is to run this query once a day and store the result in a summary table. Running a 2-second query once a day so you can get the aggregate results quickly should be acceptable. But you said you don't have authority to add a column, so I guess you don't have authority to add a table either.

In that case, get a faster computer with more RAM.

Comment: I wonder if a [covering index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_covering_index) would help? It won't remove the big scan; there's no magic to averaging a whole mess of rows. But it might help.  `alter table ccu add key bk1 (app_id, (cast(audit_create as date)), ccu);`

Comment: I tried that before, but it doesn't improve the optimization plan. It's still **type: index**. But I'm testing with an empty table (zero rows), which can cause a degenerate optimization plan.

Comment: Dang those degenerates!   :-)  Optimization plans laying around on the beach drinking cheap beer! What is the world coming to?

Comment: LOL - I mean a mathematical degenerate case, e.g. a point is a circle with radius of zero. Using EXPLAIN on a query when the tables contain zero rows reports an optimization plan that may not be the same when the tables have a representative amount of data.

Answer (score 2):

Trivial improvement:  `DATE(NOW())` --> `CURDATE()`

Main improvement:

Get rid of `id` and change

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
UNIQUE KEY `ccu_game_create_time_2a10bc69_idx` (`app_id`,`audit_create`) USING BTREE,
```

to just

```
PRIMARY KEY (`app_id`,`audit_create`),
```

That avoids a secondary lookup for each row.

There seem to be 2.4M rows (out of 11M) in the 29 day range.  The Optimizer had to decide whether to use the index (which it did), but suffer 2.4M extra lookups, versus scan all 11M rows, necessitating an extra sort.

Another thing to check is `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.  If the table is so big that it won't fit in that cache, there may be a lot of I/O.  (Again, my index change will help with that.)

Yes, Bill's generated column is likely to add more performance, independently of my suggestion.

Caution:
*Your* range is 29 days + 1 second.
*Bill's* range is 30 days.

Regardless of the datatype of `audit_create`, this works to get exactly 29 days *before* this morning:

```
WHERE audit_create >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 29 DAY
  AND audit_create  < CURDATE()
```